# Red shift for an observer outside the gravitational field

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation, gravity, equivalence-principle, redshift

Assuming there are no forces around,consider the situation:

A multi storey laboratory is accelerating in free space, for convenience say vertically. In it a light pulse is generated. The people in upper stories inside the lab will see a red shift.

Now consider a far off observer, towards which the lab is accelerating.
Will he observe any change in the wavelength?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the observer towards which the lab is accelerating will observe blueshift increasing in time due to Doppler's effect.

Comment: Can you please explain how ? When a pulse is emitted it doesn't have any link with the lab so why any shift at all?

Comment: Search for the Doppler effect.

Comment: Yes thank you got it. If you don't mind can I ask, can we get the same result by somehow using the equivalence principle?

Comment: I don't see how, Doppler's effect happens even without gravity or acceleration, gravitational redshift requires gravity or acceleration.

Comment: Thank you, I was mixing up things.